# Custom UIControl (slider) does not abide by constraints until interacted with

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, uicontrol

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift) to build a custom slider that subclasses `UIControl`. It works great when the control is programmatically inserted into the view, with the exact size, position, etc.

However, I wanted to use Storyboard to visually align the components of my view, so I added `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` to the custom slider class. Here's my problem:

1. In the Storyboard, I added the custom slider and added constraints for "Trailing Space to superview" and "Leading Space to superview".
2. However, when I run it on my device, initially it doesn't respect the constraints set above, **until I interact with the slider** (touch the button) and suddenly the constraints are enforced.
3. I tried to call `setNeedsDisplay` in the `init (coder: NSCoder)` method, but nothing works.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` in `init` is obviously too early. Try `viewWillAppear` and also try calling `layoutSubviews` on the controller's `view`.

But of course, the underlying error is a misconfiguration in the storyboard. (That would be difficult to debug via this platform).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Looks like the trick was to override layoutSubviews in my custom UIControl and then call the setNeedsDisplay, etc there.

Comment: @Mundi where do you set layer frame/bounds for a custom UIControl?

Comment: @PetrusTheron You shouldn't. Use layout constraints.